# Symfony : Validate email parameter with ParamFetcher

Tags: php, symfony

Dears,

I want to validate email directly in the RequestParam.
I'm using this kind of REGEX:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

But the parser failed to load the regex in requirements option

```
The parameter \"&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$\" must be defined.
```

How could I validate email something like that:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Patch(
 *     "v1/customer/update",
 *     name="Update a customer"
 * )
 * @RequestParam(
 *     name="email",
 *     requirements="email",
 *     description="The email of the user",
 *     strict=true
 *     )
 */
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to escape special characters. If it doesn't work, you can always register a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a service to get and convert a parameter to a Value Object, which also validates it as it is being created. I find this allows for a great deal more control than can be given in the RequestParam validations.

```
# In the same way a string is converted to a Entity, we can convert to a Vo\Username
username_converter:
    class: Ca\Api\Request\ParamConverter\UsernameConverter
    tags:
        - { name: request.param_converter, priority: -2, converter: username_converter }
```

The `UsernameConverter` class was quite simple to create as well, following the [example](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter) and the built-in `DoctrineParamConverter`, but by putting the value into an object, which is also checked, it was even easier, as there was no database access required.

If the Value Object constructor validation failed, like this (this would be for an email):

```
if (!filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"%s" is not a valid email', $address));
}
```

then the exception is caught by the framework.